# WiFi won’t work

Tags: wireless, 18.04

Sorry if this isn’t specific but how do I get my WiFi to work on Ubuntu 18.04 it just says no WiFi to connect to

Comment: Please start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay will do friend

Comment: I put in the code what do I do next

Comment: Paste it as described in the link and give us the link.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/cjxTmBnMwp/ @chili555

Comment: You pasted the code itself; please run the code as I described in the link and post the results.

Comment: @chili555 what should language do i run it in and how i pastebin

Comment: The link is quite clear: ./wireless-info  It then prepares a big report that includes all the diagnostics we need. Highlight it all, copy and paste it here: http://paste.ubuntu.com give us the link.

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CTR3tc7mk3/ @chili555 i believe this is it

Comment: Yes! I will propose a solution tomorrow morning.

Comment: kk ty my dude means a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a working driver for your device. However, as your paste result shows, the signals to all available networks is quite weak. This makes it difficult to connect and, once connected, it makes it difficult to stay connected reliably.

Quite often, the weak signal is a symptom of the antenna wire being connected to connection #1 on the card when the default driver is expecting to see the signal at connection #2. Of course, you could open the laptop and switch the wire or you could implement antenna selection at the driver level.

From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement? If not, run the sequence again with ant_sel=1 and reboot again.

We also see some things that you might tweak to make your connection more reliable.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Is there any improvement?

Comment: Is it now working as expected? If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour

Comment: now when I try to start Ubuntu it stays at a pinkish screen

Comment: Please ask a new question. I feel it is unrelated to the wireless.

Comment: Nvm I just fixed it

Comment: how would I uninstall this driver

Comment: To replace it with a different driver or to stop using the internal wireless altogether? The approaches are different for each.

Comment: get rid of it completely

Comment: If you want to get rid of it completely, blacklist it. From the terminal: `sudo -i` followed by: `echo "blacklist rtl8723be"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` followed by: `exit` Reboot.

Comment: do u have another driver that won’t screw up my computer

Comment: Screw up your computer?? How? Above, when I asked if you wanted to replace it or remove it entirely, you said remove. Did I misunderstand you? Please start a new question and give us full details.

Comment: I started the new ask